# Google Maps Suddenly stopped working on our site

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I setup google maps and it was working fine but just spotted that is is no longer firing any hints would be welcome I am not getting any error messages in the console either which is even more annoying so not quite sure why its not working:

```
<div class="img-thumbnail">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
<script>
function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' +
  'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
function initialize() {
  var map_options = {
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.500690, -0.152819),
       zoom: 17,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), map_options);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 map: map,
                 position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.500690, -0.152819)
           });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:"<b>The Caledonian Club</b><br/>9 Halkin Street<br/>London<br />SW1X 7DR" });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){ 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use the ["experimental version" (v=3.exp)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) in production**.  That will break without warning (at least it will more often than the "release" version).

Comment: That said, your existing code [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/vy2qnpzc/2/), maybe you changed your css?  The code you posted doesn't specify a size for the map_canvas div.

Comment: I am wondering if perhaps google has blocked our domain or it was a temporary glitch  but cannot test that theory as the server now seems to be down lol The size is actually in the stylesheet